# Quadcopter vertical dynamics modelling Matlab

Tags: matlab

I try to get state-space model of my quadcopter vertical motion under gravity.

I can't simulate effect of gravity. For this i try to add matrix K to my state-space model, but without success. There is no difference if i use:

```
sys = idss(A,B,C,D,K,x0,timestep)
```

or

```
sys = ss(A,B,C,D,timestep)
```

Result same. There is code:

```
clear all
timestep = 0.002;
m = 0.0027;
g = 9.81;
T_hover = 20000;
Kt = g*m/T_hover;

A = [1 timestep ; 0 1];
B = [+(Kt/m)*(timestep^2)/2 ;  +(Kt/m)*timestep];
K = [ -(g)*(timestep^2)/2 ;   -(g)*timestep];
C = [1 0];
D = [0];
x0 = [0; 0];
sys = idss(A,B,C,D,K,x0,timestep)

length = 2000;
inputm = zeros(length,1);
inputm(300:500) = 25000;
t = 0:timestep:(length-1)*timestep;

[y_m,t_m,x_m] = lsim(sys,inputm,t,x0);
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(inputm);
title('input thrust');
ylim([-1000 26000]);
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x_m);
legend('coordinate','speed');
```

Maybe i missed something obvious, give me advice, please.

Comment: Is this a programming problem or modeling problem? I did not find any programming error!

Comment: It is modelling problem. Simple model don't work.

Comment: I think it is not an appropriate place to ask questions about physical modelling! but generally, a quadcopter/quadrotor in space has six degree of freedom and hovering equation is not independent. it depends on the other generalized coordinates and their derivatives. You may use Euler-Lagrange method for modelling of such a system and then, SIMULATE it using Matlab!